# ElasticSearch nested query filtered with multiple terms using Nest DSL syntax not working as expected

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to build a nested query that needs to filter by multiple terms on the nested object. I'm using Nest nuget package version 6.1

The query is build using Nest DSL syntax as follows:

```
queryContainer &= Query<PropertyDTO>.Nested(n => n
    .Path(p => p.Publications)
    .Query(q =>
        q.Term(t => t
            .Field(ff => ff.Publications.First().Id == publicationId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        )
        && q.DateRange(r =>
            r
            .Field(f => f.Publications.First().PublishedOn)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals(
                from.HasValue
                ? DateMath.Anchored(from.Value)
                : DateMath.Anchored(DateTime.MinValue)
            )
            .LessThanOrEquals(
                to.HasValue
                ? DateMath.Anchored(to.Value)
                : DateMath.Anchored(DateTime.Now)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The expected results should be:

```
{
  "nested": {
    "query": 
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "publications.publishedOn": {
                    "gte": "2018-06-13T00:00:00",
                    "lte": "2018-06-20T23:59:59"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "publications.id": {
                    "value": "1.510136"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
    "path": "publications"
  }
}
```

But on the contrary, I get:

```
{
  "nested": {
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "publications.id": {
          "value": "1.510136"
        }
      }
    },
    "path": "publications"
  }
},
{
  "nested": {
    "query": {
      "range": {
        "publications.publishedOn": {
          "gte": "2018-06-14T00:00:00",
          "lte": "2018-06-21T23:59:59"
        }
      }
    },
    "path": "publications"
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

At the moment I'm using a workaround based on a raw query version, but I would like to use the Nest DSL syntax which is more refactoring friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
lESResponse = lESClient.Search<PropertyDTO>(s => s
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Nested(n => n
                            .Path("publications")
                            .Query(qu => qu
                                .Bool(b => b
                                    .Must(new QueryContainer[] {
                                        new DateRangeQuery() {
                                            Field = "publications.publishedOn",
                                            GreaterThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(DateTime.MinValue),
                                            LessThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(DateTime.Now)
                                        },
                                        new TermQuery() {
                                            Field = "publications.id",
                                            Value = "1.510136"
                                        }
                                    } ))))));
```

Below is the output:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "publications.publishedOn": {
                  "gte": "",
                  "lte": "2018-06-21T18:35:17.1274477+05:30"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "publications.id": {
                  "value": "1.510136"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "path": "publications"
    }
  }
}
```